# jquery panel slide Out and In + scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, jquery-slider

Hey all I have the following code that supposed to slide a div on top of a google map to show location information.

However, it doesn't seem to want to slide at all. Once it hit the test button *click to slide panel* it just seems to pop into place instead of sliding in/out. It also seems to have messed up my scrolling for that div as well. I can no longer scroll through the information using the overflow-x scroll-bar.

It should slide in from the right side in the corner as shown here in the image:

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    load();

    $('#click').click(function() {
        $('.slider').toggle("slide", {
            direction: "left",
            distance: -180
        }, 500);
    });
});

function load() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
    });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");

    locationSelect.onchange = function() {
        var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;

        if (markerNum != "none"){
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
        }
    };
}
```

And the HTML for it:

```
<div>
    <div align="center" id="zipBox">
            Zip code: <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="10" style="border: solid 1px #000000; width: 40px;" maxlength="5" />
            Radius: <select id="radiusSelect" style="border: solid 1px #000000;">
                <option value="5" selected="selected">05 miles</option>
                <option value="10">10 miles</option>
                <option value="15">15 miles</option>
                <option value="20">20 miles</option>
                <option value="25">25 miles</option>
                <option value="30">30 miles</option>
                <option value="40">40 miles</option>
                <option value="50">50 miles</option>
                <option value="60">60 miles</option>
                <option value="70">70 miles</option>
            </select>

            <input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search" style="border: solid 1px #000000;" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="locationSelect" style="width:100%;visibility:hidden"></select>
          <div align="right" class="slider">
              <p align="center">
                  <div dir='ltr' align="center">
                      <strong>Event Location:</strong><br>
                      This is the event name here!<br>
                      1510 E Woodlands St
                  </div>
                  <div align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">
                      <strong>Event Dates/Times:</strong><br>
                      11/25/2014 @ 10:00AM
                  </div>
              </p>
              <p align="center">
                  <div dir='ltr' align="center">
                      <strong>Event Location:</strong><br>
                      This is the event name here!<br>
                      1510 E Woodlands St
                  </div>
                  <div align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">
                      <strong>Event Dates/Times:</strong><br>
                      11/25/2014 @ 10:00AM
                  </div>
              </p>
              <p align="center">
                  <div dir='ltr' align="center">
                      <strong>Event Location:</strong><br>
                      This is the event name here!<br>
                      1510 E Woodlands St
                  </div>
                  <div align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">
                      <strong>Event Dates/Times:</strong><br>
                      11/25/2014 @ 10:00AM
                  </div>
              </p>
              <p align="center">
                  <div dir='ltr' align="center">
                      <strong>Event Location:</strong><br>
                      This is the event name here!<br>
                      1510 E Woodlands St
                  </div>
                  <div align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">
                      <strong>Event Dates/Times:</strong><br>
                      11/25/2014 @ 10:00AM
                  </div>
              </p>
              <p align="center">
                  <div dir='ltr' align="center">
                      <strong>Event Location:</strong><br>
                      This is the event name here!<br>
                      1510 E Woodlands St
                  </div>
                  <div align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">
                      <strong>Event Dates/Times:</strong><br>
                      11/25/2014 @ 10:00AM
                  </div>
              </p>
              <p align="center">
                  <div dir='ltr' align="center">
                      <strong>Event Location:</strong><br>
                      This is the event name here!<br>
                      1510 E Woodlands St
                  </div>
                  <div align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">
                      <strong>Event Dates/Times:</strong><br>
                      11/25/2014 @ 10:00AM
                  </div>
              </p>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mapAndInfo">
        <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
    </div>
        <div id="click" style="background: #000; color: #fff; width: 300px; height: 30px;">click to slide panel
    </div>
</div>
```

And now the CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#zipBox {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 598px;
    width: 798px;
    z-index: 10000;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: transparent\9;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4cffffff,endColorstr=#4cffffff);
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10002;
    width: 170px;
    height: 590px;
    left: 320px;
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    padding: 5px;
    right: -280px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: transparent\9;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ccffffff,endColorstr=#ccffffff);
    display: none;
}
```

**Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36yfz1nb/) of it!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't have jquery-ui loaded in your fiddle.  Your code works fine, I changed the CSS on `.slider` to

```
position: absolute;
...
right: 0;
```

and took out the `left` property.  I don't know if that's what you wanted.  But [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/36yfz1nb/1/)'s a working demo.  Cheers.

Comment: It doesn't align now with the google maps div. It alllllll the way to the right side of the screen instead of over the google maps area.

Comment: Ah, forgot to add the UI js. Thanks, bowheart!

Comment: Just play with the left and right properties, then, until the div is where you want it.  I just didn't understand why you wanted it `left: 320` and `right: -280`.

Answer (score 0):

For animate to take effect you need to add `position:relative` or `position:absolute`

http://jsfiddle.net/36yfz1nb/2/

```
.slider{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle but if you strech out the window and click the button to slide you can see its hugging the right side and not sliding out within the google maps div area.